# Country specific emergency numbers.

Tags: twilio

Is it possible to use Twilio to call country specific emergency numbers. I already have the specific numbers (for each country) in my DB. My question is if I can use the sip-trunking emergency calling for dialing emergency numbers in other countries.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can place emergency number calls in some situations but there are limitations. you can read more about it [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sip-trunking/emergency-calling).

In summary, though, to enable emergency calling on a Twilio number you need to do the following:

- Configure, validate and associate an address with your Twilio number (from the Numbers tab of your Trunk)
- Enable Emergency Calling on that number

Emergency calls (911) will only be routed when Twilio Numbers enabled for Emergency Calling are used as the Caller-ID (SIP `From:` header). Emergency calls from any other number will be rejected.